# get SSH key fingerprint in (old) hex format on new version of openssh

Tags: linux, ssh, freebsd, openssh

It seems that openssh has changed the way it displays key fingerprints.

I am trying to ssh from a client machine to a server:

- client: ubuntu 14.04 running OpenSSH 6.6.1
- server: FreeBSD running OpenSSH 7.2p2.

The client reports the md5 hash of the server's key as a sequence of 16 pairs of hex digits, like this:

> `a7:b1:3e:3d:84:24:a2:5a:91:5f:6f:e9:cf:dd:2b:6a`

The server defaults to using the sha256 hash, but thanks to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/929567/46443) I can force it to give the sha1 hash by running:

> `[root@host /etc/ssh]# ssh-keygen -l -E sha1 -f ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub`

I want the result to look like this:

> `a7:b1:3e:3d:84:24:a2:5a:91:5f:6f:e9:cf:dd:2b:6a`

but instead I get this:

> `256 SHA1:KIh0ejR4O+RqrSq7JdGAASddRfI root@host.local (ECDSA)`

It looks to me like a base64 encoded version of the fingerprint is now being displayed instead of hex digits.

**How can I get the checksum of the server's key in the same format as that reported by the (older) client (colon separated hex digits, sha1 hash) so as to check that they are the same?**

**EDIT:**
The old version of SSH gives the *md5* checksum, *not* the sha1 checksum as I mistakenly thought.  Using that checksum (as the now accepted answer should state) in the -E option gives the desired output.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

> The client reports the sha1 hash of the server's key as a sequence of 16 pairs of hex digits, like this:
>
> ```
>     a7:b1:3e:3d:84:24:a2:5a:91:5f:6f:e9:cf:dd:2b:6a
> ```

This is MD5 hash.

As you can see running

```
ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
```

will get you the same fingerprint you need without such harakiri you are explaining in your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work.  My question contains the result of running your suggested command.  Newer versions of ssh-keygen give the md5 hash as a (base64 encoded?) string instead of a hex string.  "All that harakiri"  (an apt description!) is the easiest way i could find to get an old style hex string from the new version of openssh tools.

Comment: Unless FreeBSD break something (or removed MD5 support), there is no reason why it should not work. Note that your command lists wrongly `sha1` instead of `md5`! I have outdated Ubuntu version with openssh-6.9, but it works just fine.

Comment: md5 instead of sha1... not sure how I missed that.  That does indeed give matching output.

Comment: I have the opposite problem. I have the md5 and want the other format. How do I get it?

Comment: Works when command is executed on ubuntu. Does not work when command is executed on centos.

Comment: @MarinosAn it depends on which version. CentOS 6 is old and you will get this output by default, CentOS 7 should work this way already.

Comment: it seems that with older ssh-keygen's, `-E` is not supported.

Comment: @einpoklum no, it is not, but it uses md5 by default so there is no need for that.

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 22. I also do not believe this is MD5 of a fingerprint anyway. My cert sha256 Fingerprint is AB:CD:EF:...:YZ and SHA1 Fingerprint is AA:BB:CC...:ZZ (`openssl x509 -in CERT.pem -noout -sha256 -fingerprint`). However, SSH fingerprint verification always outputs `ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:Blablablastring` or `ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA1:blablashorterstring`. `ssh -o FingerprintHash=md5` option gives some totally different fingerprint not matching any of the above.

Comment: This can be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985106/convert-ed25519-to-rsa-fingerprint-or-how-to-find-ssh-fingerprint

Comment: @igor X509 OpenSSL fingerprint is something totally different than the OpenSSH key fingerprint. Running the ssh will print fingerprint of the server hostkeys and not your local key. Please, provide whole commands you used/tried, what are you trying to achieve or better open a new question with all these information.

Answer (score 8):

In cases like this I use the following little script (tested on Debian and Ubuntu):

```
#!/bin/sh

# Gather the public ssh host keys for the given host
# and for each key print the fingerprint in hex format using the given
# checksum command (e.g. md5sum, sha256sum, ...)

if [ "$#" != 2 ]; then
  echo "usage: $0 hostname checksum_command"
  exit 1
fi

ssh-keyscan $1 2>/dev/null | while read -r line; do
  echo "Scanned key:"
  echo $line
  echo "$2 fingerprint:"
  echo $line | awk '{print $3}' | base64 -d | $2 -b | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/../&:/g' | sed 's/:$//'
  echo
done
```

Example usage:

```
$ myscript host.example.com md5sum
Scanned key:
host.example.com ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIJUXq7vpcEpnZQxxiLw/tdg8ui4LoqbW1O5nGyLtGw49
md5sum fingerprint:
6c:ef:26:f7:98:ad:ed:5b:cc:ff:83:13:46:c9:f6:79

Scanned key:
host.example.com ssh-rsa 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
md5sum fingerprint:
b2:9c:cd:30:b1:38:e3:d1:17:d6:73:eb:03:9a:80:83

$ myscript host.example.com sha256sum
Scanned key:
host.example.com ssh-rsa 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
sha256sum fingerprint:
f4:61:58:e4:90:65:c4:70:98:7f:d1:40:0a:d8:d9:79:14:e6:91:dc:b6:ed:91:8c:c0:df:d9:65:db:dd:a0:18

Scanned key:
host.example.com ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIJUXq7vpcEpnZQxxiLw/tdg8ui4LoqbW1O5nGyLtGw49
sha256sum fingerprint:
4b:73:d1:d7:80:87:46:64:56:71:64:10:7a:66:83:9b:c7:58:39:0b:16:74:dd:9b:d9:4b:e5:d5:61:7e:99:45
```

Comment: oneliner: `ssh-keygen -l -Emd5 -f <(ssh-keyscan host.example.com)` Why use a script if a command will do?

Comment: @DrBeco: The onliner returns key fingerprint in hex format for md5 checksum. But try it with -Esha256 option -- it does not return the key in hex format. The above script is better in that regard.

Answer (score 7):

As it turns out, the [SSH Cookbook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Authentication_Keys#Downloading_keys) has a way to manually generate keys in the older hex format.  I used this on the freebsd server.

> awk '{print $2}' key.pub | base64 -d | md5 | sed 's/../&:/g; s/: .*$//'

**Breaking this down:**

> awk '{print $2}' key.pub

print out the second (space separated) column in "key.pub", which is the key itself

> base64 -d

the key is base64 encoded.  This will output the actual bytes of the key

> md5

this is freebsd's equivalent of the 'md5sum -b' that was specified in the recipe on the ssh cookbook page

> sed 's/../&:/g; s/: .*$//'

There are two sed commands here:

> s/../&:/g;

replace every pair of characters on the line (thanks to the 'g' flag at the end) with that same pair followed by a colon

> s/: .*$//'

remove any trailing colon (replace a colon followed by a space followed by anything up to the end of the line with nothing).

Answer (score 1):

ssh -o FingerprintHash=md5 user@host...