# Can’t specify which fingerprint hash to use

Tags: openssh

When I try this command it fails:

```
ssh -o FingerprintHash=sha256 example.com
```

Error message: `command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: fingerprinthash`

Why is this? Has this option been removed from OpenSSH? My ssh client version is `OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`.

My intention is to verify the fingerprint from the client’s output with the fingerprint sent to me by the sysadmin, which was in another format (base64-encoded SHA256, I believe).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`FingerprintHash` option](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#FingerprintHash) is available since [OpenSSH 6.8](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.8) only.

Earlier versions always use MD5.

---

See also [SHA256 ssh fingerprint given by the client but only md5 fingerprint known for server](https://superuser.com/q/929566/213663).